# Kivy Update Widget

Tags: python, kivy

I read in a text file called data.txt containing the usernames and passwords. The format of the text file is:

username1
password1
username2
password2
username3
username3
etc.

I read in the usernames and make a corresponding button for each username. When I first start the program, it shows everything in data.txt and works. However, when I add a user using the program, it does not update the list of users on the main screen. How would I update the list?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from numpy import loadtxt
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from os.path import sep, expanduser, isdir, dirname
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class AddUserWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (AddUserWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        addNewUserLayout = FloatLayout()
        newUserLabel = Label(text="User Name:", font_size='15dp', size_hint = (.5, .05), pos = (500, 450), halign = 'right')
        passwordLabel = Label(text="Password:", font_size='15dp', size_hint = (.5, .05), pos = (500, 400), halign = 'right')
        confirmPasswordLabel = Label(text="Confirm Password:", font_size='15dp', size_hint = (.5, .05), pos = (500, 350), halign = 'right')
        self.newUserInput = TextInput(text = "", size_hint = (.25, .05), pos = (875, 450), font_size='15dp', multiline = False, write_tab = False)
        self.passwordInput = TextInput(text = "", password = True, size_hint = (.25, .05), pos = (875, 400), font_size='15dp', multiline = False, write_tab = False)
        self.confirmPasswordInput = TextInput(text = "", password = True, size_hint = (.25, .05), pos = (875, 350), font_size='15dp', multiline = False, write_tab = False)
        cancelButton = Button(text="Cancel",size_hint = (.2, .05), pos =  (650,0))
        cancelButton.bind(on_press = self.changeToMainWindow)
        okButton = Button(text="Ok",size_hint = (.2, .05), pos =  (350,0))
        okButton.bind(on_press=self.newUserCheck)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(cancelButton)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(okButton)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(newUserLabel)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(passwordLabel)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(confirmPasswordLabel)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(self.newUserInput)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(self.passwordInput)
        addNewUserLayout.add_widget(self.confirmPasswordInput)

        self.add_widget(addNewUserLayout)

    def newUserCheck(self, *args):

        if self.newUserInput.text == "":
            content = Button(text = 'Close')
            popup = Popup(title = 'Please enter user name', size_hint = (.4, .15), content = content, auto_dismiss = False)
            content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
            popup.open()
            return

        if self.passwordInput.text == "":
            content = Button(text = 'Close')
            popup = Popup(title = 'Please enter password', size_hint = (.4, .15), content = content, auto_dismiss = False)
            content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
            popup.open()
            return

        if self.confirmPasswordInput.text == "":
            content = Button(text = 'Close')
            popup = Popup(title = 'Please confirm password', size_hint = (.4, .15), content = content, auto_dismiss = False)
            content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
            popup.open()
            return

        if self.passwordInput.text != self.confirmPasswordInput.text:
            content = Button(text = 'Close')
            popup = Popup(title = 'Passwords must match', size_hint = (.4, .15), content = content, auto_dismiss = False)
            content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
            popup.open()
            return


        file = open('data.txt', 'r')
        initial = file.readlines()
        databaselines = sum(1 for line in open('data.txt'))
        file.close()


        users = databaselines / 2
        data = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(users)]
        currLine = 0
        range(users)
        for i in range(users):
            data[i][0] = initial[currLine].rstrip()
            data[i][1] = initial[currLine + 1].rstrip()
            currLine += 2

        inDatabase = 0
        for i in range(users):
            if data[i][0] == self.newUserInput.text:
                inDatabase = 1
                break
        if inDatabase == 1:
            content = Button(text = 'Close')
            popup = Popup(title = 'Already in database', size_hint = (.4, .15), content = content, auto_dismiss = False)
            content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
            popup.open()
            return

        with open("data.txt", "a") as dataFile:
            dataFile.write(self.newUserInput.text + "\n")
            dataFile.write(self.passwordInput.text + "\n")
        self.changeToMainWindow


    def changeToMainWindow(self, *args):
        self.newUserInput.text = ""
        self.passwordInput.text = ""
        self.confirmPasswordInput.text = ""
        self.manager.current = 'mainScreen'

class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (MainWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.mainLayout = FloatLayout()

        logoutButton = Button(text="Logout",size_hint = (.2, .1), pos =  (650,0))
        logoutButton.bind(on_press = exit)
        addNewUserButton = Button(text="New User",size_hint = (.2, .1), pos =  (350,0))
        addNewUserButton.bind(on_press=self.changeToAddUser)
        self.mainLayout.add_widget(logoutButton)
        self.mainLayout.add_widget(addNewUserButton)
        file = open('data.txt', 'r')
        initial = file.readlines()
        databaselines = sum(1 for line in open('data.txt'))
        file.close()


        users = databaselines / 2
        data = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(users)]
        currLine = 0
        range(users)
        for i in range(users):
            data[i][0] = initial[currLine].rstrip()
            data[i][1] = initial[currLine + 1].rstrip()
            currLine += 2

        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(users):
            self.btn = Button(text=data[i][0], size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint=(.45, None), pos = (600, 100), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.mainLayout.add_widget(self.root)
        self.add_widget(self.mainLayout)




    def changeToAddUser(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'addUserScreen'



class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.my_screenmanager = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition())
            self.mainScreen = MainWindow(name='mainScreen')
            self.addUserScreen = AddUserWindow(name = 'addUserScreen')
            self.my_screenmanager.add_widget(self.mainScreen)
            self.my_screenmanager.add_widget(self.addUserScreen)

            Window.size = (1200, 800)
            return self.my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can define a function which adds the appropriate widgets to the layout or you can "clean" the layout and read every user from the database again. If you have many users this might take a while.

To add users via a function:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (MainWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        [... create initial widgets ...]

        [... read users from database ...]

        for i in range(users):
            self.add_user(data[i][0]

        self.root = ScrollView(size_hint=(.45, None), pos = (600, 100), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        self.root.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.mainLayout.add_widget(self.root)
        self.add_widget(self.mainLayout)

    def add_user(self, text):
         button = Button(text=text, size_hint_y=None, height=40)
         self.layout.add_widget(button)
```

then when adding a new user:

```
def newUserCheck(self, *args):

    [... do checks ...]
    [... write to file ...]

    # replace `text` with whatever text you want to display
    self.manager.get_screen("mainScreen").add_user(text) 

    # in your shown code you missed the () on this function call
    self.changeToMainWindow()
```

Also I personally found your code relatively hard to read. You could create some functions and call them e.g. `create_initial_widgets`, `read_users_from_database`, `write_user_to_database` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing this but then I ran into the problem of calling a function from another class. I am new to Kivy so I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: What exactly did not work? I just see that I missed a `self` in the definition of `add_user`, maybe that was it? generally there is no real difference between calling a function from the own class (via `self`) or from some other class (via a variable that holds on object of that class).

Comment: I believe you that it works but I literally do not know how I would call add_user. add_user is in the MainWindow class and I am trying to call add_user from the AddUserWindow class. Sorry I'm a bit slow, I am still trying to pick up Kivy and Python

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere. You have to get a "handle" on the MainWindow object which is "hidden" inside the manager. The screen is saved in `self.manager`. Then you can get screens by calling `self.manager.get_screen("name_of_screen")`. Because you named the main window "mainScreen" you can get it via `self.manager.get_screen("mainScreen")` and then just call the function from that object i.e. `self.manager.get_screen("mainScreen").add_user(args)`. Of course you could also safe the screen in a variable `mainScreen = self.manager.get_screen("mainScreen")` if you wanted.